# Qual o numero de casas decimais do tipo NUMBER(12,2)?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Como saber o número de casas decimais para o tipo NUMBER(12, 2) em um banco Oracle ?

```
V_FATURA NUMBER(12, 2)
```

Comment: Ué, é 2. A precisão é 12,2

Comment: Essa é a dúvida mesmo? Tem algum motivo extra para perguntar algo óbvio assim?

Comment: Pensando em alguma coisa diferente do óbvio, talvez a pergunta seja referente à quantidade de casas decimais.. ex: _1.11_ teria "precisão" de dois; _1.10_, de um; e _1.00_, de zero.. seria isso??

Comment: Em um software no qual estou realizando manutenção, recebi uma mensagem de erro relacionado  a o tipo number(12,2) porém não tinha conhecimento do conceito do tipo de dado no oracle.  Agradeço a todos compartilharam seu conhecimento comigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tipo `NUMBER` em Oracle tem a seguinte sintaxe:

> NUMBER[(precisão [, escala])]

Onde precisão define quantos "caracteres" seu número terá e a escala define quantas casas decimais.

Por exemplo:

> NUMBER(12,2)

Aceitará até o número `9999999999,99`

Fonte: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Number